# Android App using RabbitMQ of cloudfoundry

Tags: android, chat, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry

Hi i am trying to develop a chat application in Android using RabbitMQ. 
The code is working fine with my locally installed rabbitMQ server.

Inordrer to send message to the queue my android APP needs the address of the robbitMQ server it is talking to.
Can I make use of RabbitMQ on cloudfoundry,  replacing my local rabbitMQ  in the  application code ?

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
 factory.setHost("<RobbitMQ server>");


 Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
 Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
 channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "fanout", true);
 channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll face a couple of issues with this:

1. the address of the RabbitMQ service on cloudfoundry.com will be dynamically-assigned... you can look it up from the environment on cloudfoundry.com within a web app, but you can't easily get it in a remote native Android app.
2. right now, you can't make a remote AMQP connection into a service on cloudfoundry.com - only *within* the Cloud Foundry vcap environment. So even if you had the address, an AMQP connection via JMS directly from an Android app wouldn't work.

How about running RabbitMQ on an EC2 instance? or what about building a web app backend for your Android app, which talked to RabbitMQ running in a Cloud Foundry instance, with Android talking to the backend via SockJS?

Comment: Thanks andy.. I guess i will build a webapp using comet for the long pooling

Comment: I'd encourage you to look at SockJS instead of Comet, it is from the RabbitMQ team and works well with both long polling and websockets.

Comment: Thanks, i will explore Sock.js. Having said that the Comet might need me to modify Servlet.xml for the org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol. Will cloudfoundry allow you to modify Servelt.xml ?